# Configure grunt.js to minify files one by one in bower folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have the dependencies of the application in **bower_components**, some of the dependencies **don't have a minified version** so I'd like to create a task creates a minified copy of the file version in the same place where the file is located like:

- bower_components

  - lib1

    - lib1.js
    - lib1.min.js **<- create this file if doesn't exist**
  - lib2

    - lib2.js
    - lib2.min.js **<- create this file in it's own lib2 folder**
  - lib3

    - lib3.js
    - lib3.min.js **<- and so on...**

This is my grunt Config so far:

```
 uglify: {
        dev: {
            files:[
            {
                expand: true,
                src: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
                dest: '/',
                ext:'.min.js'
            }, {
                expand: true,
                src: 'bower_components/angular-facebook/lin/angular-facebook.js',
                dest: '/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }]
            },
                main: {
                    src: 'temp/app.min.js',
                    dest:'dist/app.min.js'
                }
            }
```

the Grunt task says that copied modernizr to it's own folder but when I look at it, the file is not there and after the first file Grunt passes to the next task and ignores the 'second' file in the array.

I was just testing this obviously I'd like to implement a way that grunt **scan all** the **dependencies** in **bower_components** automatically.

btw, I don't mind to change the task to any other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `/` in your `dest`-option means the root path (were your gruntfile resides). just delete the `dest`-option or put an empty string there.

important: this just works with the `expand`-option set!

```
{
  expand: true,
  src: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
  ext:'.min.js'
}
```

**Edit:**

for scanning all folders an minimizing all js files do it like this (note the second argument in src to not minify files which are already minified):

```
{
  expand: true,
  src: ['bower_components/**/*.js', '!bower_components/**/*.min.js'],
  ext:'.min.js'
}
```

Comment: what about to scan N number of files inside the bower_components folder?